# With in Version Difference (DifferenceTypeUpdateNoChange) how to pass IQueryFilter in ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, c#, enterprise-geodatabase

I want to know only real shape edits between 2 versions. How can I pass iQueryfilter to DifferenceTypeUpdateNoChange?

```
public void DifferenceTypeUpdateNoChange(ITable sourceTable, ITable differenceTable, esriDifferenceType differenceType, iQueryfilter Qf)
        {
            IQueryFilter qf = new QueryFilterClass();
            qf.SubFields = "SHAPE.AREA,SHAPE.LEN";
            qf.WhereClause = "SHAPE.AREA,SHAPE.LEN";    
            try
            {
                IVersionedTable versionedTable = (IVersionedTable)sourceTable;
                IDifferenceCursor differenceCursor = versionedTable.Differences(differenceTable, differenceType, Qf);
                IRow differenceRow;
                int objectID;
                differenceCursor.Next(out objectID, out differenceRow);
                //Detect and output all the differences between the two versions
                int count = 0;
                while (objectID != -1)
                {                    
                    Console.WriteLine(FClassName + "," + objectID + "," + " has been modified");
                    //WriteCSV(FClassName, objectID, "Updated Feature");
                    differenceCursor.Next(out objectID, out differenceRow);                   
                    count++;
                }                
                //sw.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new-ish user, please take the [Tour]. All code should always be formatted as code (4 leading spaces -- press the `{}` button in the web interface).

Comment: Don't forget to call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(differenceCursor)` after the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is to detect all changes (inserts, updates and deletes) for a version based upon a query filter, then the target versioned table should be opened from the common ancestor version using IVersion2::GetCommonAncestor. The common ancestor version is the representation of the table when the source version was first created or last reconciled with the target version. This will ensure the results are all the rows which meet the definition of the query filter

You can see sample for GetCommonAncestor on : https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#72dfe883-e4d7-4925-835c-02bc513f91aa.htm